# Mass file comment - Copyright Purposes

Tags: php

Is there any way or any application that can automatically add a new line and comment on your files?

Something like:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Created by _____
////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

I have PHP Projects where I wanted to put comments on every file for copyrights purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a script, bash or powershell, to append it to every php file. You would first want to grep or search the file to see if it had already been appended. This would be automatic as much as you ran the script, which could be a part of your normal build if you use other systems like grunt or gulp for things like resource minification.